# Whenever I press start in Gooey Python, the give me an error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, decorator, python-decorators

```
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser




@Gooey
def main():
    """Takes 2 number as input and output the sum"""
    parser = GooeyParser()
    parser.add_argument("num_1", help="Enter num1", action= "store")
    parser.add_argument("num_2", help="Enter num2", action= "store")
 
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(int(args.num_1) + int(args.num_2))


main()
```

The interface opens, I enter a num1 value and num2 value as input and when I click start to make the sum, it isn't working. They tell me "path is not specified"

Do you know what we can do to display the answer?

below traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eclrod\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 3427, in <lambda>
    lambda event: event.callable(*event.args, **event.kw) )
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\eclrod\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\gooey\gui\containers\application.py", line 92, in onStart
    self.clientRunner.run(self.buildCliString())
  File "C:\Users\eclrod\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\gooey\gui\processor.py", line 53, in run
    self._process = subprocess.Popen(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__     
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified
```

Comment: If there is a traceback error, please include it in your post.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in my Windows 11 with Python 3.12.1 and Gooey 1.0.8.1.

Comment: below traceback error:

Answer (score 0):

no error from my side python 3.11.7 and gooey  1.0.8.1 on Windows 11

Can you add a type and see if it's better :

```
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser

@Gooey
def main():
    """Takes 2 number as input and output the sum"""
    parser = GooeyParser()
    parser.add_argument("num_1", type=int, help="Enter num1", action= "store") 
    parser.add_argument("num_2", type=int, help="Enter num2", action= "store")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(int(args.num_1) + int(args.num_2))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding your last information, you use the 1.2.0a0 version which is a pre-version, please use the 1.0.8.1 instead:

```
pip uninstall Gooey
pip install Gooey==1.0.8.1
```

I think this ticket can be closed?